# Hex HMAC MD5 input hex(hmacmd5(input)) javascript

Tags: javascript, input, hex, md5, hmac

I have tried a few JavaScript libraries but none seem to have this functionality? Does anyone know how to return data `hex(hmacmd5(input))` with JavaScript ?

Comment: Cryptography is JavaScript is usually a misunderstanding in how you should be using cryptography. Can you explain your use case?

Comment: thats all i have to go on unfortunately.. and that says exactly what it does on the tin. this is taken from a C++ application hex(hmacmd5(input)) from what i can see its Hex Hmacmd5 input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CryptoJS.HmacMD5(input.toString(), key);